What does df actually display?
Today I was using tar to backup the /var directory of my server. At some point, I noticed that this is taking very long, so I used du to figure out how large /var is. It was about 76 GB. My disk had only about 60 GB of free space. Nevertheless, I let it run, maybe the compression rate would be good enough.
Later, df -h showed Available 0 for the disk which is mounted on /. But tar still didn't exit due to missing disk space. The tar archive still grew further.
Example output:
16:28:16 $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      237563280 226454128         0 100% /

As we can see, the disk is 237 GB, only 226 GB are used, but 0 is available. Where is the rest? What does df actually display?

Depending of the FS type, you have some space reserved for root. Check it by running tune2fs /dev/sda3

@admstg: that just print usage options, but from what I see, the command should be fine.

df shows the filesystem's statistics for space consumed and space available.  du recursively reads directories and performs calls like stat() to get the space consumed by each file and sums them into a total.  The simple explanation for the difference is: files that consume space but don't appear in directories, or when the filesystem has reserved space.  The duplicate question(s) have more detail.

tune2fs needs the -l option to display the filesystem parameters, so the command to run would be tune2fs -l /dev/sda3.
